# Joining tables and counting instances

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to do the following

I want to count the number of times a risk code has been dialled and also group it by its Risk code, But if it doesn't have a risk code I want to name it no risk code and also count how many times it appears

i.e

Table call data contains the following

```
Number|Name|Contacttime|userref
075   |Jim | 10:00     | 1112
072   |Jim | 10:01     | 1112
077   |Bob | 10:00     | 1111
099   |Jane| 10:01     | 1000
```

RiskTable

```
Number|Name|RiskGroup  |userref
075   |Jim |H          | 1112
072   |Jim |M          | 1112
077   |Bob |L          | 1111
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
with cte as ( 
select u.name, isnull(riskgroup, 'NoRisk') as riskGroup from CallData as u  
left join RiskTable as r on r.name = u.name  )

select count(*) , riskgroup from cte group by riskGroup
```

Result sample:

```
count       riskgroup
----------- --------------------
2           H
1           L
2           M
1           NoRisk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), b.RiskGroup
FROM CallData a
JOIN RiskTable b
ON a.Number = b.Number
GROUP BY b.RiskGroup;
```

I think that should give you the COUNTS for each RiskGroup, which the GROUP BY handles.
The JOIN links the two tables ON the common field Number.
As for giving a blank RiskGroup a different name other than the default (null), I'm not too sure how to deal with that.

Maybe try doing this separate query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NoRiskCode
FROM CallData a
WHERE a.Number NOT IN (
    SELECT Number FROM RiskTable
);
```

This counts how many records are in the CallData table that have Numbers which don't exist in the RiskTable.

Comment: if it doesn't have a risk group associated with it can the code above count it?

Comment: The JOIN will ignore records from the CallData table that do not have a matching Number from the RiskTable. I have edited my answer to provide a separate query to handle that though.

Comment: Check out my answer, I _think_ is what you are looking for.